# OpenCv - Exception at memory location C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this program that loads in a video file, lets the user decide on the threshold value, and then writes out the video's "threshold representation" frame-by-frame. When i build and run it it works, but not before throwing the "Exception at memory location.."
What's the problem?
Thanks!

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat frame3, frame4;
int tValue = 100;

//the function that is called when the tracker is moved
void callFunc(int, void*) {
    threshold(frame3, frame4, tValue, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    imshow("Threshold Adjustment", frame4);
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{

    VideoCapture cap("C:/video/park.avi");
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    int frm_count = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);


    Mat frame1;
    cap.set(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0);
    cap >> frame1;
    Mat frame2;
    cap.set(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 1);
    cap >> frame2;

    //calculates the absolute difference between two frames
    absdiff(frame1, frame2, frame3);
    namedWindow("Threshold Adjustment", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    createTrackbar("Value", "Threshold Adjustment", &tValue, 255, callFunc);
    callFunc(0, 0);


    switch (waitKey(0)) {
    case 27:
        Size framesize(cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
        VideoWriter output_cap("D:/out.avi", CV_FOURCC('D','I', 'V', '3'), cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS), framesize, 1);
        for (int k = 0; k < frm_count; k++) {
            cap.set(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, k);
            cap >> frame1;
            cap.set(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, k + 1);
            cap >> frame2;
            absdiff(frame1, frame2, frame3);
            threshold(frame3, frame4, tValue, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
            output_cap.write(frame4);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in switch never getting the value 27. Try this:

```
char key = waitKey(0);
switch (key){
```

The difference is that you store the result of waitkey in a char variable, so if you press ESC the value would be 27. The way you do it, it store the result of waitkey in a int variable so you get the value 1048603.

You could also only change 27 by 1048603 in your code.

Comment: Interesting but it didn't work:(  on the contrary, when i press escape (27) the program does work - it does render out the resulting video, it just doesn't exit properly because of that exception it throws. When i press any other key (not escape) it exits properly but of course doesn't render out the video.

Comment: Ok. It happened to me when I tried your code. So, where do the program stops if you run it in debug mode? I can execute your code with no problem... (apparently)

Comment: I can execute the code as well, and it works, it's just that after it finishes running and writing out the video, it throws that exception.. didn't you get that exception when you ran the code?

Comment: I think the exception is because of frame3. Try to put `frame3.release();` it worked for me